# How to parse 100 json from wireshark?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I need to simulate one program 100 times, I need to have one simulation per hour (The duration of one simulation is 1 hour). From every simulation, I want to generate different json. My program must be stopped only be tapping 'exit' I try too to make that works:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
import os
def simulation():
    os.system("./program")
    print ("tshark -i tun0 -T ek > path/packets_one_hour.json")

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(some_job, 'interval', hours=1)
scheduler.start()
```

My problem is that my script is running without stopping. I can't generate 100 different json files. I must put `quit` after every hour in order to generate a new and different json. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Couldn't each simulation time itself and quit after an hour is up?

Comment: @martineau  Yes It is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Refering to [this](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/master/examples/schedulers/blocking.py) example from apscheduler docs, you could do the following.

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import threading

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def json_dump():
    # Put here your dump script
    pass


def simulation():
    os.system("./program")
    t = threading.Timer(3600, json_dump)
    t.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(simulation, 'interval', hours=1, id='id_sim')
    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

    try:
        scheduler.start()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
```

Honestly, haven't tried it. Let me know if it works.